# pass data to inertiajs with view composer in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, inertiajs

Im using Laravel 8 with Jetstream(Inertia stack).

i want to pass data to my Inertia components with view composers.

how do i do that?

i even tried this but doesn't work:

```
View::composer('*', ProfileComposer::class);
```

if you want more info here it is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Http\View\Composers\ProfileComposer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('*', ProfileComposer::class);
    }
}
```

and also here is another part:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\View\Composers;

use App\Models\Center;
use App\Models\Field;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class ProfileComposer
{
    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\View\View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('centers', Center::all('id', 'name'))
            ->with('fields', Field::all('id', 'name'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inertia replaces blade views so you should pass data to inertia directly. so if you want for example to share a data to all views you should use: `Inertia::share(..)`

see: [Inertia share](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data)

Comment: I only want to pass my data to `user/profile` route. i don't want to pass my data to all routes and query my database while there is no need.

Comment: you can in the route/controllers return `inertia('component', ['data' => data::All()])` just like `view()`

Comment: im using jetstream and some `routes` or `controllers` cant be edited. since it's in `vendor` directory and can't be published.